# what's the difference between <a> and <button> and <Link> from react-router-dom?

Tags: html, reactjs

What's the difference between these three tags feature?
Which one is the best practice?

```
<a href='/questions/aks'> Routing to Ask Question Page </a>

<Link to='/questions/aks' /> Routing to Ask Question Page </Link>

const handleButtonClick = () => {
  navigate('/questions/aks')
}
<button onClick={handleButtonClick}> Routing to Ask Question Page </button>
```

I'm writing CRA application using react, react-router-dom, styled-components
I want to change url path(routing) when user click html element.
I've tried three of them but I haven't notice key difference.
Can anyone explain me about these concepts?

Comment: Is there a specific difference between these elements and components that can't be understood from reading documentation? This post is a bit too broad and open-ended. What sort of comparison are you looking for? What specifically do you need help understanding? Please [edit] to clarify and narrow the focus of the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite you can use these 3 for redirect these are some of the differences:

- < a > element is the native browser element for redirection, it behaves without any extra javascript functionality and the browser is capable to understand back and forward buttons in the browser
- < Link > is the react-router-dom React Component. It at the end renders < a > element in HTML and has logic inside of it, it uses react-router-dom API in order to work, once you use it you can take profit of some react-router-dom functionalities related to that library
- < button > element is another native element in browser, the main difference between < a > and < button > is semantics, < a > is intended to be used with redirections and < button > to execute functions after click

You can redirect with < button > and use onClick in < a > element but semantically will be incorrect.

Semantics are the right using of the elements in HTML

Answer (score 0):

i think a tag is redirect there
Link tag too
when you using router? then you feel change maybe
my answer is not sure

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).